# Spark Scala data frames grades classifying

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Hello I have original data like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtr7P.jpg) I want to add a column based in a break point of 80 as a pass grade and the results should be as [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHJLv.jpg). I am using sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") to read the original data. any help!

Comment: I have tried using .withColumn("columnname", but I cannot solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

using `.withColumn()` will work as expected:

```
val resultUDF = udf( (total: Int) => if(total >= 80) "pass" else "fail")
df.withColumn("result", resultUDF($"total"))
```

Comment: Thank u but I am getting this error <error>: <error> any suggestion !

Comment: post the full `stack trace`

Comment: This is what I am trying to do :    val resultUDF = udf( ("Bin %" : Int) => if("Bin %" >= "80") "pass" else "fail")
dTestSample1.withColumn("result", resultUDF($"Bin %")).show()            and cannot run it bcz of <error>: <error>

Comment: what is `Bin %`, is that a column name?

Comment: It is a column name

Comment: First rename the column, it should'nt contain any whitespaces. and run the `.withColumn()` again

Comment: `df.withColumnRenamed("Bin %","BinPercent")`

Comment: Hmm I renamed the column but a strange thing happens in the results df.withColumnRenamed("Bin %","BinPercent").show()       
       
    result +--------------+------------+
              |grades        |BinPercent  |
              +--------------+-------------         the column renamed but when I print schema root
 |-- grades: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Bin %: string (nullable = true)      so when I use .withColumn() I get this error given input columns: [grades, Bin %];;

Comment: don't use the old `df` for `.printSchema()`. use the new `dataframe` name. you should run: `val df1 = df.withColumnRenamed("Bin %","BinPercent")` then `df1.printSchema()`

Comment: Is that a problem if the column Bin % which is BinPercent has values like 77.84 %? does the white space make a problem ?

Comment: and this my organized code   val df=dTestSample1.withColumnRenamed("Bin %","BinPercent").select("grades", "BinPercent")          
   df.printSchema()     
   val resultUDF = udf( (BinPercent : Int) => if(BinPercent >= 80) "pass" else "fail")
df.withColumn("result", resultUDF($"BinPercent")).show() and as results for the column 'result' I get null values

Comment: `.withColumnRenamed()` renames the column name. it has nothing to do with values in that column.

Comment: based on your comment if it has values like: "77.84 %" then its your job to clean the values. remove the `%` and convert it as `double` type. before sending it to `UDF`

Comment: I solved the problem by using .withColumn("results%", when(col("BinPercent") >= "90.00 %", "pass").otherwise("fail"))   Thanks for your cooperation and sorry for to much complex. Cheers!

Comment: Nope, thats not correct `col("BinPercent") >= "90.00 %"` here you are doing a `string` comparison. not the `double` value

Comment: I see can you please show me how to remove % and change the column type to double ?

Comment: Assuming the value has only one whitespace between marks & "%", modify the results UDF like: `val resultUDF = udf( (BinPercent : String) => {
 val splits = BinPercent.split(" ")(0).toDouble
 if(splits >= 80) "pass" else "fail"
})`